# How do I unlock privacy in multiplayer modes mission settings?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

Ever since I started playing Mass Effect 3 Multiplayer, the privacy setting in mission settings is locked. I own the legendary or best edition so if there was a code in there I missed it. Is there something I have to do or get a certain amount of characters to level 20? [image]

Comment: It doesn't look locked to me on your screenshot. Are you sure you can't change it to public?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, that is not my screen. I searched the net for that so people would know exactly what I was talking about in case my questions was confusing.
On mine, there is an actual lock on the right hand side of the Private panel.

Comment: I'm assuming you're not referring to the Quick Match screen, where you can only search for public games (and so there is a lock on the team settings thing).

Comment: Well call up Hostess and tell them they have a Ding-Dong missing! Thats the only screen I know of. How do I get to the normal online gaming page?

Comment: The "Private" panel you are referring to is the match type for a custom game. You cannot choose a Private mission when choosing Quick Match from the Multiplayer menu.

Comment: I'll double check tonight to make sure, but thank you everyone for your help! When I say make sure, I mean that is unlocked in a non-quickmatch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When starting a multiplayer game,you have two options: Quick Match and Create New Match.

With Create New Match, you can choose either private game or public game. Public game means that anyone can join. Private game means that only people you invite can join. (And I think your friends can also join without invitation.)

With Quick Match, you search for a game that already exists. And it doesn't make sense to look for a private game, so the option is locked.

To sum up, if you want to *create* a private game, use Create New Match, not Quick Match.

Also, there are no requirements for this, you can always do it .